# Adding values to a queue and wait before showing them

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm making a website that is a *wakling simulator*. It's an exercice I decided to have to learn things in javascript and Jquery.

The idea is that you are always walking and you can set destinations to go and walk in. You can set as many destinations as you want, if so, they get in a queue and `.position` is updated with the new destination **as soon as you finish walking in the previous place** (not immediately like it's the case for now).

**Here is the storytelling :**

1. You are "Somewhere" which is a starting position
2. As soon as you enter a value in the input **(and press enter)**, it stores that value to make it the *destination* and generate a random number of steps for it. It then `.append()` so you can see it; and its shown for the number of steps of it (which is `stepsDestination`) in `.position`.
3. You are now walking to your destination for the number of steps it shows.
4. as soon as you enter another destination in the input it add it to the "queue" so as soon as your first destination is reached, you'll start to walk in your second destination (the previous destination is removed from the queue)
5. (also, you can add some other destinations to have as many as you want)

I managed to create the walking simulation but I don't know how I could have a real queue for the destinations **that waits for each of them to be finished** before showing them in `.position` for their specific number of steps.

Thanks a lot for the precious help.

```js
var maxSteps = 500;
var i = 0;
var nbOfSteps = 0;
var timer;
var timer2;
var destination = "Somewhere";
var stepsDestination = 0;

function incrementDoc() {
  nbOfSteps++;
  var restant =  maxSteps-nbOfSteps
  $("<div />", {
    "class": "maxSteps"
  })
  .css({})
  .append($("<p> <br>" + nbOfSteps + " steps </p>"))
  .append($("<p> remaining " + restant + " steps to walk </p>"))
  .appendTo(".recap")
  $(".maxSteps").prev().remove();
  
      $("<div />", {
    "class": "position"
  })
  .css({})
  .append($("<p>" + destination + "</p>"))
  .appendTo(".position")
  $(".position").prev().remove();
  
  if (++i >= maxSteps) {
    clearInterval(timer);
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#destination').keyup(function(e){

    if(e.keyCode == 13 ){ 
      if(destination == "Somewhere"){ // this if() is activated on the first time as there is not yet any destination
      destination = $('#destination').val()
      $('#destination').val('');
                $(".info").remove();
      var stepsDestination = Math.floor((Math.random() * 150) + 50);
      console.log(destination + stepsDestination)

      $("<div />", {"class": "direction"})
      .css({ "font-size" : '1.3rem'})
      .append($("<p>" + destination +" for "+ stepsDestination + " steps</p>"))
      .appendTo(".queue");
      maxSteps = stepsDestination;
    } else {
    
     destination = $('#destination').val() //get the destination specified
      $('#destination').val(''); // clear the input

      var stepsDestination = Math.floor((Math.random() * 150) + 50); // set a random value of steps for that specific destination
      console.log(destination + stepsDestination)

      $("<div />", {"class": "direction"})
      .css({ "font-size" : '1.3rem'})
      .append($("<p>" + destination +" for "+ stepsDestination + " steps</p>"))
      .appendTo(".queue");
      maxSteps += stepsDestination; // adding the steps to the steps already there
    }
  }

});

  timer = setInterval(incrementDoc, 1000);

});
```

```css
.position{
  position : fixed;
  left : 50vw;
  color: red;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.recap{
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.queue{
  background: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class= "position"></div>
<p class= "info">
when you set your first destination it's going to start. while "Somewhere" is there, you are just wandering for 500 steps.
</p>
<input id="destination" autocomplete="off" name="name"/>
<div class= "recap"> total of steps walked and remaning steps</div>
<div class= "queue">Queue :</div>
```

**EDIT**

So I managed to find the value of the new destination. But that's it.

```
  var DestinationStepsRemaining = stepsDestination - nbOfSteps;
      console.log(DestinationStepsRemaining + " steps remaining")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. I set `stepsDestination` to a lower value for testing purposes. If you have any question, or this didn't work (I haven't tested it so well), please let me know in the comments.
Also, this may not be the best solution as I did not integrate it with the rest of your code. I just looked at the issue and solved it (hopefully!) on its own, without taking into consideration, the rest of your code. I would also say that your way of spending elements to the DOM is far from good practice, and it also makes your code harder to read. I would suggest using the `appendChild()` method, which you can read more about here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp and here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild. Good luck!

```js
var maxSteps = 0;
var i = 0;
var nbOfSteps = 0;
var timer;
var timer2;
var destination = "Somewhere";
var stepsDestination = 0;
var place = [];
var placeCounter = 0;
var first = 0;

function incrementDoc() {
  if (placeCounter == 0) {
    document.getElementById('position').innerHTML = place[0].place;
  }
  nbOfSteps++;
  var restant = maxSteps - nbOfSteps;
  document.getElementById('log').innerHTML = '<br> ' + nbOfSteps + ' steps <br><br>' + "remaining " + restant + " steps to walk";

  if (restant == 0) {
    if (!(place[placeCounter+1] === undefined)) {
      placeCounter++;
      maxSteps = place[placeCounter].time;
      nbOfSteps = 0;
      document.getElementById('position').innerHTML = place[placeCounter].place;
      restant = maxSteps;
    } else {
      clearInterval(timer);
      console.log('last in queue');
    }
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#destination').keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      destination = $('#destination').val() //get the destination specified
      $('#destination').val(''); // clear the input
      var stepsDestination = Math.floor((Math.random() * 13) + 4); // set a random value of steps for that specific destination
      place[place.length] = {
        time: stepsDestination,
        place: destination
      };
      console.log(destination + stepsDestination);
      $("<div />", {
          "class": "direction"
        })
        .css({
          "font-size": '1.3rem'
        })
        .append($("<p>" + destination + " for " + stepsDestination + " steps</p>"))
        .appendTo(".queue");
      if (first == 0) {
        maxSteps = stepsDestination;
        timer = setInterval(incrementDoc, 1000);
        first = 1;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#position {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50vw;
  color: red;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

#recap {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.queue {
  background: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="position"></div>
<p class="info">
  when you set your first destination it's going to start. while "Somewhere" is there, you are just wandering for 500 steps.
</p>

<div id='position'>
</div>
<input id="destination" autocomplete="off" name="name" />
<div id="recap"> total of steps walked and remaning steps
  <div id='log'>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="queue">Queue :</div>
```

Comment: Hi!
Thanks a lot for the work, This is working quite well and I still have to configure it for my website!
Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I'm having one question though, How can I update `.position` with the next destination in queue as soon as it reaches the end of the previous one?
Actually it's updated with the destination but as soon as you press enter.

Comment: Hey, I've been explore the code a bit and I still can't seem to manage to get the last destination and update it for `.position` as soon as the previous one is over.
So i'm asking for a bit of light there, it's that's ok with you!
Thanks a lot

Comment: I'll take a look at it.

Comment: @pual if you don't mind can you tell me how you are deleting the old queue destinations?

Comment: I'm not able to delete them, the snippet I posted is all I managed to do.
Deleting the previous destination in queue is one of the thing I wanted to have in order to show the person walking an updated list of the places he decided to go. So as soon as you reach the next destination, the previous one is deleted from the "queue" (which could be renamed "next destinations")

Comment: ok, i thought I broke it when it wasn't working, still trying to find the best solution

Comment: haha, that's fine, thanks a lot for your time.
I hope everything is clear, but I can try to explain it again if you need. :)

Comment: haha yes! It seems to be working!
I need now to find a way to remove them for the queue and keep a correct track of the steps.
Thanks a lot. you killed it :)

Comment: glad I could help ;)